# How to remove component from DOM?

Tags: angular

I am wondering how I can remove my component form DOM manually? I've been looking at `ElementRef`, and found some work arounds there, but I've been wondering if there is any function dedicated to do this?

My set up is the following:

I've got a `Loader` component, that is called via EventEmitter. I am adding it to a view by `DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation(..)`, and then I want to remove it from the view.

I've also found `Renderer.destroyView(component)`, but this yields me to errors.

Thanks

Comment: Please share more information. What kind of element do you want to remove from where?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, provided more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(this.type, this.elRef, 'target').then((cmpRef) => {
  this.cmpRef = cmpRef;
});
```

then remove it with:

```
this.cmpRef.dispose();
```

See also [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Answer (score -1):

you can use `*ngIf`of `angular2` which will added the Element to DOM if condition result is true, In case of results False it does't allow to render the Element on DOM

Comment: I don't think this is a valid solution because I think meanwhile the component is checking for the *ngIf condition to be true it is still loaded into memory and using resources. I guess this question is about how to destroy the component, not just to make it not visible.